# Ansible versioning on git

Tags: git, ansible, gitlab

I've got a git repo, I've got my playbooks and hosts. Now what?

What is the recommended way to get my /etc/ansible folder on my GitLab? I can just create the repo, but then how and when do I pull this? What about the .git folders?

I tried keeping a copy on /home/user/git/ansible and symlink that to /etc/ansible but ansible can't follow that.

How should this be done?

(I'm also interested in some good reads about how to work properly with git)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I store nothing in /etc/ansible. But I install and run ansible using a virtualenv so /etc/ansible was never there for me.

You definitely should look at the [official recommended layout](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html), but my minimal ansible hierachy is as follow:

```
inventories
    hosts
    vars
roles
    role1
    role2
    ....
ansible.cfg
site.yml
```

I clone the repository to /home/victor/git/ansible and I put these lines in my bashrc to set the default ansible paths:

```
export ANSIBLE_INVENTORY=/home/victor/git/ansible/inventories/hosts
export ANSIBLE_CONFIG=/home/victor/git/ansible/ansible.cfg
```

There are two rules that I always follow:

1. Everytime before I run a playbook, I pull from git to make sure I am running the latest version.
2. Whenever I make a change to the playbook, I would always run them first to make sure there are no error before I commit to the repository.

If you are using ansible to distribute secrets or credentials, you also want to use ansible-vault to encrypt them before you commit to git. **DO NOT put any plain credentials on a git repository.**

I suppose in this use case having a .git folder is not an issue at all (I guess you didn't want a .git folder somewhere in /etc/).

Comment: For sensible data,  such as passwords/keys, you can use `ansible-vault` to encrypt it before pushing.

Comment: @Mr Shunz That sounds really useful. I will include this in the answer.